# How to properly use liquibase `searchPath` option to indicate the respective resource folders?

Tags: bash, liquibase

I'm trying to invoke the `update` command of `liquibase` like follows:

```bash
liquibase update --changelog-file=./persistence/src/main/resources/changelog/db.changelog-dev.xml \
                 --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sigma"
```

This results in:

```
[...]
Starting Liquibase at 23:44:47 (version 4.17.2 #5255 built at 2022-11-01 18:07+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.17.2
Liquibase Community 4.17.2 by Liquibase

Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file classpath:/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml was not found in the configured search path:
    - /Users/ikaerom/Dev/sigma-backend
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/liquibase-core.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/lib
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/jaybird.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/ojdbc8.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/snakeyaml.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/snowflake-jdbc.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/picocli.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/jaxb-runtime.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/jaxb-api.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/jaxb-core.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/hsqldb.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/connector-api.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/mssql-jdbc.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/h2.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/mariadb-java-client.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/liquibase-commercial.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/commons-lang3.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/postgresql.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/sqlite-jdbc.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/opencsv.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/commons-text.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/commons-collections4.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib/jcc.jar
    - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/liquibase/4.17.2/libexec/internal/lib
More locations can be added with the 'searchPath' parameter.
```

The `db.changelog-dev.xml` is essentially including `db.changelog-master.xml`, which then also references some SQL scripts. The two XML files lie in the same resource folder `$PROJECT_ROOT/persistence/src/main/resources/changelog`. The imported/included SQL files referenced within the changelog XML all lie in the resource folder's subfolders.

Any way of specifying this eluding `searchPath` or even `--search-path` parameter (as indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/how-liquibase-finds-files.html)) seems to fail spectacularly:

```bash
$> liquibase update --searchPath="./persistence/src/main/resources/" --changelog-file=./persistence/src/main/resources/changelog/db.changelog-dev.xml --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sigma"
Unexpected argument(s): --searchPath=./persistence/src/main/resources/
```

So let's try the other indicated syntax:

```bash
$> liquibase update --search-path="./persistence/src/main/resources/" --changelog-file=./persistence/src/main/resources/changelog/db.changelog-dev.xml --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sigma"
Unexpected argument(s): --search-path=./persistence/src/main/resources/
```

If I attempt to use `LIQUIBASE_SEARCH_PATH=`, I end up with this:

```
[...]
Liquibase Version: 4.17.2
Liquibase Community 4.17.2 by Liquibase

Liquibase Community detected and ignored the following environment variables:
- LIQUIBASE_SEARCH_PATH
To configure Liquibase with environment variables requires a Liquibase Pro or Liquibase Labs license. Get a free trial at https://liquibase.com/trial. Options include the liquibase.licenseKey in the defaults file, adding a flag in the CLI, and more. Learn more at https://docs.liquibase.com.
[...]
```

I don't really want to buy a pro version just to get this feature working ;).

**My question is**: how do I specify the search path for `liquibase` to pick it up in my bash shell?

I find it hard to believe that this wouldn't work, given `liquibase` is so well documented, and it tries to always give you the correct hints and pointers, if you don't use it correctly. What did I miss?

**Update**: I have a suspicion that the order of invocation matters. So, the `update` command should be last in the list. However, no luck so far:

```bash
$> liquibase \
          --changelog-file=./persistence/src/main/resources/changelog/db.changelog-dev.xml \
          --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sigma" \
          --searchpath="./persistence/src/main/resources/changelog/" \
          update
[...]
Starting Liquibase at 14:29:51 (version 4.17.2 #5255 built at 2022-11-01 18:07+0000)
Liquibase Version: 4.17.2
Liquibase Community 4.17.2 by Liquibase

Unexpected error running Liquibase: The file ./persistence/src/main/resources/changelog/db.changelog-dev.xml was not found in the configured search path:
    - /Users/ikaerom/Dev/sigma-backend/persistence/src/main/resources/changelog
More locations can be added with the 'searchPath' parameter.

For more information, please use the --log-level flag
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution myself, after digging through the `liquibase` source code.

In my `db.changelog-dev.xm` I had a line which included `db.changelog-master.xml` as follows. That `classpath:/` has to be removed:

```
-    <include file="classpath:/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml"/>
+    <include file="changelog/db.changelog-master.xml"/>
```

Then, this invocation finally works (mind the adapted `searchPath` and the relative designation of the `changelog` parameter settings):

```bash
    liquibase \
          --hub-mode=off \
          --headless=true \
          --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sigma" \
          --searchPath="./persistence/src/main/resources" \
          --changelog-file=changelog/db.changelog-dev.xml \
          update 2>&1 | grep -Ev -- "^##"
```

The `--hub-mode=off` will prevent `liquibase` from asking if you want to connect to the liquibase hub. The rest is sugar-coating.

The only problem open is that when `liquibase` is invoked from the shell CLI, the user ending up owning the changelog/lock tables is the user invoking the `liquibase` command:

```bash
ikaerom@/tmp:sigma> \dt databasechangeloglock
+--------+-----------------------+-------+---------+
| Schema | Name                  | Type  | Owner   |
|--------+-----------------------+-------+---------|
| public | databasechangeloglock | table | ikaerom |
+--------+-----------------------+-------+---------+
SELECT 1
Time: 0.011s
ikaerom@/tmp:sigma> \dt databasechangeloglock
+--------+-----------------------+-------+---------+
| Schema | Name                  | Type  | Owner   |
|--------+-----------------------+-------+---------|
| public | databasechangeloglock | table | ikaerom |
+--------+-----------------------+-------+---------+
SELECT 1
Time: 0.010s
```

However, when `liquibase` is updated by invoking the Spring boot application, then the table owner user is the one the application context is setting (in my case sigma):

```bash
ikaerom@/tmp:sigma> \dt databasechangeloglock
+--------+-----------------------+-------+-------+
| Schema | Name                  | Type  | Owner |
|--------+-----------------------+-------+-------|
| public | databasechangeloglock | table | sigma |
+--------+-----------------------+-------+-------+
SELECT 1
Time: 0.010s
ikaerom@/tmp:sigma> \dt databasechangelog
+--------+-------------------+-------+-------+
| Schema | Name              | Type  | Owner |
|--------+-------------------+-------+-------|
| public | databasechangelog | table | sigma |
+--------+-------------------+-------+-------+
SELECT 1
Time: 0.009s
```

This clashes if you run your `liquibase` update first:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "databasechangeloglock" already exists [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE public.databasechangeloglock (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT databasechangeloglock_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:397)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:83)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:151)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:135)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:115)
    at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:286)
    ... 94 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "databasechangeloglock" already exists
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:393)
```

This again can be solved by a proper GRANT for the sigma or a re-assignment of the owner to the rightful user. Or simply by adding the `--username` property to the name of the spring boot application context or database user owner:

```bash
    liquibase \
          --hub-mode=off \
          --headless=true \
          --username="sigma" \
          --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sigma" \
          --searchPath="./persistence/src/main/resources" \
          --changelog-file=changelog/db.changelog-dev.xml \
          update 2>&1 | grep -Ev -- "^##"
```